Is there any way to access a RequestContext in a play framework endpoint?
Is there any function or a way to work around the RequestContext in PlayFramework, that works similarly to Pekko's extractRequestContext?
I'm migrating an old Akka rest API to Play3.0, and I need to port this Endpoint to play. Fortunately, Pekko has the exact same function "extractRequestContext", and the same type I need: StrictForm.FileData
The reason why I want to access the request context is because this API is using a library that needs files to be specifically of the type StrictForm.FileData, so Using a normal request.body.file("icon") is not really an option, unless I can convert those files to FileData.
post {
    extractRequestContext { _ =>
       formFields(
           "name".as[String],
           "description".as[String].?,
           "icon".as[FileData].?,
           "color".as[String]
       ) { (
               name: String,
               description: Option[String],
               icon: Option[FileData],
               color: String,
           ) => {
               onboardingController.saveData(
                   workspaceRequest(userKey, name, description, icon, color)
               )
           }
        }
    }
}

I tried to do this while using a Form, but as I said, I could not find a way to convert the file. I know the getOrElse would make it fail in case there is no file, it was just for testing purposes.
I could not find any way to access the requestContext and looking at an old PlayFramework docs, I could not find anything similar
def createWorkspace = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  request.body.file("icon").map { picture =>
    //I wanted to cast the file to StrictForm.FileData, but I did not found a way to do it.
    // handle the other form data
    workspaceForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => 
        println(errors.toString())
        BadRequest("Ooops"),
      workspaceRequest => {
        // this does not work since it returns a Part
        // val withPicture = workspaceRequest.copy(icon = Some(picture))
        Ok("")
      }
    )
  }.getOrElse(BadRequest("Missing picture."))
}


The following classes and method comes from pekko-http
org.apache.pekko.http.scaladsl.common.StrictForm.FileData

org.apache.pekko.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext
org.apache.pekko.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.extractRequestContext

pekko-http must be added as a dependency in your project with the following line if you are using sbt as your build tool
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-http" % PekkoHttpVersion

I haven't found some helper that do the transformation you need, which means you would need to do it by yourself. Something like this could work
// assuming that the function from the library is like this
def myFunction(fileData: StrictForm.FileData): SomeType = // magic

// the transformer MultipartFormData.FilePart[Files.TemporaryFile] => StrictForm.FileData
def transformTemporaryFilesToFileData(file: MultipartFormData.FilePart[Files.TemporaryFile]): StrictForm.FileData =
  StrictForm.FileData(
    filename = Option(file.filename),
    entity = HttpEntity.Strict(
      // file has a `contentType` field but is of type `Option[String]`
      // there is a helper class `ContentType` with a `parse` method that could help
      // I hardcoded the value just for this example
      contentType = ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,
      data = file.transformRefToBytes()
    )
  )

// the action to process files could be like this
def form: Action[MultipartFormData[Files.TemporaryFile]] = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  val filesData = request
    .body
    .files
    .map(transformTemporaryFilesToFileData)
    .map(myFunction)

  Ok(Json.toJson(filesData))
}

